# Excel followhyperlink method - screen flickering

Tags: excel, vba

On a main spreadsheet I'm using a vba Loop code to open spreadsheets files by using the followHyperlink method. Once a file is opened, I use another loop to check a range, cell by cell, for data. If the cell has data them before copying and pasting it in the main spreadsheet, I make sure that the cell destination is empty to avoid data override.
The code works fine but the screen flicks non stop.
I'm using:

```
application.ScreenUpdating = False  
application.DisplayAlerts  = False
```

As well as `DoEvents`, but the flickering didn't stop.

Any suggestions? Thanks

---

```
Sub ImportDataMultiFiles()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .StatusBar = "Upadating Spreadsheet"
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Dim RangeOne As Range
    Dim CellUsed As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim PathFolder As String
    Dim PathFile As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wkSheetName As String
    Dim UserRange As Range
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    PathFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    Set RangeOne = ActiveSheet.Range("B3", "B" & LastRow)
    CellUsed = Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RangeOne)
    wkSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

    For i = 3 To LastRow 'start loop
        DoEvents 'let windows catch up
        
        If Range("B" & i) <> "" Then  'if 001: checks for data in column "B" otherwise skip row
           
            PathFile = Range("B" & i).Hyperlinks(1).Address 'get hyperlink address and assing to variable
              
            ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PathFile  'open the file stored in the variable
            FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name  'get the opened file name
            
            For c = 1 To 34  'start a loop to check for data in cell(8,c) till column 34
                
                
                If wkSheetName = "Data1" Then 'IF 002: checks which worksheet the button was pressed
                
                    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wkSheetName).Cells(i, c + 7) = "" Then  'IF 003: if the cell is empty run code otherwise skip to avoid erasing data
                
                         Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("Case Info").Cells(2, c).Copy
                         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wkSheetName).Cells(i, c + 7).pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    Else
                    
                    End If 'End If 003
            
                Else
                
                    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wkSheetName).Cells(i, c + 7) = "" Then  'Code 004: if the cell is empty run code otherwise skip to avoid erasing data
                
                         Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("Case Info").Cells(2, c).Copy
                         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wkSheetName).Cells(i, c + 7).pastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    Else
                
                    End If 'End If 004
                    
                End If 'End If 002
            
                    Next c 'move to the next cell
            
        Else 'from If 001
                    
        End If 'end of code 001: Range("B" & i) <> "" Then
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Workbooks(FileName).Close  'closes after collecting all data
        
        On Error GoTo 0
        
    Next i 'move to the next hyperlink in column B
    
    End If
        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wkSheetName).Cells(3, 2).Activate 'This code brings the cursor back to top of worksheet

    
    MsgBox "Data successfully imported"
 
With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .StatusBar = ""
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Visible = False`?

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` should be outside of any loop. If you could share the complete code, there could be more suggestions to improvement.

Comment: Hi braX, thanks for the suggestions. I tried using `application.visible = false` but it didn't notice any difference.

Comment: I've add the full code